# Passing a variable with spaces from bash to awk

Tags: awk, variable

I am trying to pass a variable that contains spaces from bash to awk.  I have simple a simple script for doing this with single string variables (in which I am searching the first column of the FILE for the variable), for example:

```
var=string

awk -v v=$var '(index($1, v) !=0) {print}' FILE
```

This does not work if `var="string1 string2"`.  I have new searches where the variables are groups of words separated by spaces as in second var.  E.g.,

```
var="string1 string2 string_n"

awk -v v=$var '(index($1, v) !=0) {print}' FILE
```

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of quoting the shell expansion? i.e. `awk -v v="$var"`

Comment: I second steeldriver's comment. Also, can you not replace `(index($1,v)!=0)` with `$1~v`?

Comment: After you lose all the noise words, leaving you with `awk '$1~v' v="$var" FILE`, you'll need to use something besides whitespace for a field separator in awk.  `awk '$1~v' v="$var" FS=. FILE`

Comment: Sorry if duplicated.  I tried to check.  Also, thanks for help consolidating the code.  I'm a novice at scripting, so this is very useful.

Comment: @G-Man It is not a security question, it is a scripting question. I find the initiative to close it as a dupe of a security question surreal. The relevant security implications could be mentioned as related matter, but an answer to this question would be essentially different as the dupe candidate.

Comment: @peterh: Have you even *looked at* the other question?

Comment: @G-Man Yes. I've seen a 5 page long security-tuned scripting documentation, which includes the required roughly 3-line answer to this question.

Comment: [SE] believes in having “canonical” questions. That is the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange definitive canonical reference question on the pitfalls of failing to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells. Why the author chose to title it that way, I don’t understand; but you have judged a book by its cover — ***it*** (Stéphane Chazelas’s question) is not a security question; it is a scripting question.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Yes, the answer is “You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$var"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.” — but that’s the answer to a thousand questions, and there’s very little benefit to having the same answer duplicated on the site a thousand times — especially if it leads 1000 OPs to ask “Why?”

Comment: I just saw this question in the Reopen queue and while I agree with closing it as a duplicate, a more relevant duplicate target would be Gilles’ canonical Q&A, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan: Thanks for adding that link.  Perhaps some moderator will see this and add that to the list of duplicate targets.

Comment: In this case, @jthill comment to modify the field separator from whitespace to something else solved the issue.  Quoting the variable, though good practice that I accidentally omitted in the question, was not the ultimate issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to put `$var` into double apostrophes also in the `awk` command, so:

```
varName="a string with spaces"
awk -v var="$var" '{...your awk code...}'
```

It is because your awk command will be called by a shell, and most shells, including bash, forget the tokens after variable substitution.